# Disable loop slider in AndroidImageSlider

Tags: android, slider

At the default in [AndroidImageSlider(daimajia)](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider) we want to know when it goes to the end of slide whats the way it ll not go back to the starting.

Comment: Could you post what you have tried? Did you also try asking the project owner(s)?

Comment: yes,but he doesn't answer